# Need help for Checkbox as bool? field while rendering from view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, checkboxfor

I am facing issues with bool? ( Nullable) while rending from MVC3 view.

Model:

```
[MustBeTrue(ErrorMessageResourceName = "EmailConfirmationRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Site))]
 public bool? IsEmailConfirmed { get; set; }
```

Views:

```
 @Html.LabelFor(x => x.IsEmailConfirmed, string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0}", Site.EmailConfirmText))
<div class="inputClass" id="disabled">
<div>
 @if (Model.IsEmailConfirmed == null)
 {  Model.IsEmailConfirmed = false;  }           
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsEmailConfirmed.Value) 
  </div>
 </div> 
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.IsEmailConfirmed)
```

After ticking the checkbox from the view,the controller is not loading its object asscociated with it.  It displays "null", instead of "true" for IsEmailConfirmed. I am suspecting that the IsEmailConfirmed.Value is internally mismatched with the value IsEmailConfirmed. If not, could someone help me to resolve on this please?

Comment: You cannot use `CheckBoxFor()` for a nullable `bool`. `CheckBoxFor()` is for a `bool` only. Look at the html your generating - it has no relationship to your model property.

Comment: Hi Stephen, Thanks a lot for your instant response. Could you tell me how to write this in Checkbox in view? Any Sample code will be really helpful. I searched in stackoverflow. I got only examples using CheckBoxFor, but not Checkbox.  Kindly help me on this.

Comment: You simply cannot use `CheckBoxFor()` to bind to `bool?` A check box can only have 2 states (on/off or true/false), whereas a `bool?` has 3 states (true/false/null). Either make the property `bool`, or better use a view model with a `bool` property and if your data model is `null`, set the view model property to `false`. Alternatively if you need the option to select a `null`, use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.IsEmailConfirmed)` which will generate a dropdownlist with the 3 values.

Comment: Thanks Stephen for the valuable suggestion. Will apply it in my code.